# How can the Bevel Modifier be replicated in Geometry Nodes? (basic functions only)

Tags: geometry-nodes, bevel

Although a bevel modifier is in the works for some upcoming release, I still wonder if it could somehow be reconstructed in *Geometry Nodes* with the currently available versions (3.3 LTS, 3.4).

To reconstruct all properties of the bevel modifier would probably be an unsolvable task.

But if one would refer the function only to the pure smoothing of edges (and maybe at most the possibility to change the shape slightly), it should be feasible. ...I think.

[image]

---

This question has also been addressed in principle a few times, or there are a few that go in this direction, but cannot be seen as a duplicate:

- [Bevel effect with geo nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266655)
- [Possible to Bevel Geometry Nodes Group Output?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270558)
- [Bevel the top half of an object or just the top half of a selection using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270242)

I had also asked a similar question once before, but this one referred to a cubic shape:

- [How can I bevel the edges of a cube with geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/264169/145249)

Only that does not help me in this case.

The question posed here refers to complex geometries, which are not cubic, and therefore requires a completely different approach.

In such a case, I think the most crucial thing is that the corner points create a mesh with different number of edges, which definitely makes the task a master work.

---

Therefore, I again ask the clear question, because I myself am convinced that there must be a solution here:

> How can I smooth the edges of a complex geometry in *Geometry Nodes* without using the Bevel modifier?

I am sure that some genius brain might have a brainwave that could lead to a solution?

Comment: Good timing, IMO. Nice challenge, even if the nodes are on their way, eventually...